# ROS2 plugin does not load for clang-tidy

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a MoveIt2 PR that creates a new plugin. It's working great except CI does not pass for `galactic`. Strangely, CI does pass for `galactic-testing` and `rolling`.

It looks like there have not been any commits to the [pluginlib repo](https://github.com/ros/pluginlib/commits/galactic) in 9 months so I think `galactic` and `galactic-testing` should be the same.

Here's a [link to my PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/676). The terminal printout when CI fails is:

> Error: mponent_container_mt-2] [ERROR]
> [1634151469.735356961]
> [moveit_servo.servo_calcs]: Exception
> while loading the smoothing plugin
> 'online_signal_smoothing::ButterworthFilterPlugin':
> 'MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not
> create object of class type
> online_signal_smoothing::ButterworthFilterPlugin
> as no factory exists for it. Make sure
> that the library exists and was
> explicitly loaded through
> MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()'
> Error: ROR]
> [component_container_mt-2]: process
> has died [pid 16245, exit code 1, cmd
> '/opt/ros/galactic/lib/rclcpp_components/component_container_mt
> --ros-args -r __node:=servo_container -r __ns:=/'].

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388671/ros2-plugin-does-not-load-for-clang-tidy/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-10-14**:
One maybe-unusual thing is that I created a plugin within the same package as the base class. I think the base class and the actual plugins are usually in different packages.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-14**:
`galactic-testing` is a MoveIt specific "thing" AFAICT ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/bbcf9a06ccc90943f06500c00ed385b8045f0df3/.github/workflows/ci.yaml#L25), a Docker image name, hosted at `ghcr.io/ros-planning/moveit2`). It's not a branch of `pluginlib`, nor is there a ROS 2 package repository which has a `galactic-testing` version.

The way you refer to it in your question implies you are under the impression it is something part of the regular ROS 2 repositories / distribution channels.

Could you clarify?

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-10-19**:
I'm sure you're probably right. So the question boils down to, why does the `galactic` docker image cause issues but `galactic-testing` does not...

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-10-19**:
Maybe it's due to this `clang-tidy: pedantic`?

```
      - IMAGE: galactic-ci
        CLANG_TIDY: pedantic
      - IMAGE: galactic-ci-testing
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-20**:
Seeing as it's so MoveIt specific, should you not ask the people who set this up?

**Comment by [henningkayser](https://answers.ros.org/users/87637/henningkayser/) on 2021-10-20**:
`galactic-testing` is simply using a docker image that uses the `ros2-testing` repository for `galactic`. Since the build works just fine without `clang_tidy: pedantic`, I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the plugin configuration and clang. There are plenty of other plugins in MoveIt that work just fine with clang, though.
My thought is that the plugin base itself doesn't have a library target that is separate from the plugin. It's only provided with a simple header file. Since the base class is purely abstract, clang will only create a vtable in the plugin translation unit. The classloader has no way to access the vtable of the plugin base before loading the plugin itself. I wonder if pure virtual plugin base classes are even really supported of if they should be inline or at least need some default constructors/destructors.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-10-20**:
They are making some suggestions. Removing `CLANG_TIDY: pedantic` does fix it. I'll try a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We finally found a solution that works for the clang compiler. It involved:

- Careful declaration of constructors/destructors
- A separate libary for the plugin base class

I'm not sure which of these were necessary.

Full details in Henning's commits here:  https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/676

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0